# How to get rid of the shape inside a shape

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, artifacts

[image]

Hello guys, when i enter into Edit mode, i always get this shape inside the mesh.
(I'm talking about the rectangle inside the cube) does anybody knows how to remove it? or what its for? (if its suppose to be there)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it look from different angles? Does it appear to be actual geometry or some kind of visual artifact?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still see the shape if you go to wireframe mode ("Z" on keyboard...)

If it is still there but you do not see the vertex points it is another object which is placed inside your object... Leave the edit mode and move away the outer shape to see (and delete) the inner object...

Comment: In wireframe mode it's gone, anyways most probably I have tweaked some critical settings there, I have reset to factory settings ands its gone totally.